# Show/hide tinymce with radio buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I try to show/hide a tinymce with radobutton. Like yes/no. So there are two radio buttons. yes - will show the tiny mce and no will hide the tinymce.

I have this:

showing tiny mce:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.PdfMessage, new { @class = "text-bold control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => mailModel.PdfMessage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control tiny-mce", data_lang = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name, id = "tinyMCE" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => mailModel.PdfMessage)
        @*@Html.TextArea("MailProductHandlers_message", mailModel.Message, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = 15 })*@
    </div>
</div>
```

these are my radio buttons:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.GeneratePDF, new {@class = "text-bold control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">

        @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.GeneratePDFYes)  @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsChecked, "Yes", new { @checked = true, id = "radioButton" })
        @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.GeneratePDFNo)  @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsChecked, "No", new { @checked = true, id = "radioButton2" })

    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[Id='radioButton']").click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('#tiny-mce').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#tiny-mce').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

if I do this:  `$('#mceu_61').hide();` it hides the editor. but after I press on yes, it shows the editor. but if I then press No it doesnt hide anymore. And I have this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => mailModel.PdfMessage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control tiny-mce", @id = "mceu_61", data_lang = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name } })
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: This doesnt work. It doesnt show/hide

Comment: I think you want @id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing an @symbol for the id attribute:
Modify your script as well like this:

***EDIT some thing seems off about the radio buttons only one should be checked and they should have the same name **

you can use the # to denote and ID in Jquery by the way instead off looking it up by attribute

**EDIT I changed a few things around, I don't think you need two individual ids I grouped them with a class, you should be able to check the on change event from that class instead of checking on both ids**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => mailModel.PdfMessage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control tiny-mce", @id = "tinyMCE", @data_lang = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name  } })


@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsChecked, "Yes", new { @checked = true, @class = "pdfchecker" })

// only one should be checked
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsChecked, "No", new { @checked = false, @class = "pdfchecker" })



<script>
    // this is short hand for document ready
    $(function () {
        //# is to denote an ID, . is to denote a class in jQuery the change function is hit when a radio button is change check the name to make sure they are apart of the same grouping
        $(".pdfchecker").change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('#tiny-mce').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#tiny-mce').hide();
            }
   });






</script>
```

Comment: Oke, thank you. And in my model I have IsChecked as a int. I will try it. I let you know if it works –